# CRUD in React, update item using useState not working

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to create a CRUD using `React Hooks`  but I am having some problems on the `updateItem function`.
The first input using `useState` works perfectly (I can type inside the input) but when I click Rename Item, the second input appears but I can’t type inside and doesn’t log any errors from console.

Here is my code:

```
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import React, { useState } from 'react';

function App() {

//List with one item
const [list, setList] = useState([{ id: Math.random() + 1, name: 'Test' }]);

//Inputs
const [input, setInput] = useState('');
const [newInput, setNewInput] = useState('');

const [edit, setEdit] = useState();

function createItem(value) {
    if (!value.trim()) return;

    let obj = { id: Math.random() + 1, name: value }
    setList([...list, obj])
}

function deleteItem(id) {
    setList(list.filter(item => item.id !== id));
}

function updateItem(id) {
    setEdit(
        <div>
            //I can't type anything in here 
            <input type="text" value={newInput} onChange={e => setNewInput(e.target.value)} />
            <button onClick={() => {
                let array = [...list];

                array.map((item, i) => {
                    if (item.id === id) array[i] = { id, newInput }
                })

                setList([...array])
                setEdit('') //Remove the edit from the DOM

            }}>Rename</button>
        </div>
    )
}

return (
    <div>
        <input type="text" value={input} onChange={e => setInput(e.target.value)} />
        <button onClick={() => createItem(input)}>Add Item</button>

        {list.map(item => (
            <div key={item.id}>
                <p>{item.name}</p>
                <button onClick={() => updateItem(item.id)}>Rename Item</button>
                <button onClick={() => deleteItem(item.id)}>Delete Item</button>
            </div>
        ))}

        {edit}
    </div>
);
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use **setEdit** to show/hide through boolean value. You will have ability to type in the input

```
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import React, { useState } from "react";

function App() {
  //List with one item
  const [list, setList] = useState([{ id: Math.random() + 1, name: "Test" }]);

  //Inputs
  const [input, setInput] = useState("");
  const [newInput, setNewInput] = useState("");

  const [edit, setEdit] = useState(false);

  function createItem(value) {
    if (!value.trim()) return;

    let obj = { id: Math.random() + 1, name: value };
    setList([...list, obj]);
  }

  function deleteItem(id) {
    setList(list.filter(item => item.id !== id));
  }

  function updateItem() {
    setEdit(true);
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <input
        type="text"
        value={input}
        onChange={e => setInput(e.target.value)}
      />
      <button onClick={() => createItem(input)}>Add Item</button>

      {list.map(item => (
        <div key={item.id}>
          <p>{item.name}</p>
          <button onClick={() => updateItem(item.id)}>Rename Item</button>
          <button onClick={() => deleteItem(item.id)}>Delete Item</button>
          {edit && (
            <div>
              //I can't type anything in here
              <input
                type="text"
                value={newInput}
                onChange={e => {
                  setNewInput(e.target.value);
                }}
              />
              <button
                onClick={() => {
                  let array = [...list];

                  array.map((o, i) => {
                    if (o.id === item.id) array[i] = { id: item.id, newInput };
                  });

                  setList([...array]);
                  setEdit(false); //Remove the edit from the DOM
                }}
              >
                Rename
              </button>
            </div>
          )}
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with how you run `updateItem()` function.
You are using the following call `<button onClick={() => updateItem(item.id)}>Rename Item</button>`
In `updateItem()`, you do a `setEdit` and it adds an input box and button to your screen.
But now, you have trouble updating the input box. This is because the input box will only be updated when you run the `updateItem()` function again.
So in order for your input box to be updated, you would have to run `setEdit` again

Here is a solution of how to put it in your main component so that the input box updates with each render

```
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import React, { useState } from "react";

function App() {
  //List with one item
  const [list, setList] = useState([{ id: Math.random() + 1, name: "Test" }]);

  //Inputs
  const [input2, setInput2] = useState("");
  const [newInput, setNewInput] = useState("");

  const [edit, setEdit] = useState(null);

  function createItem(value) {
    if (!value.trim()) return;

    let obj = { id: Math.random() + 1, name: value };
    setList([...list, obj]);
  }

  function deleteItem(id) {
    setList(list.filter((item) => item.id !== id));
  }

  function renameItem() {
    // Rename item
    alert("Rename item " + edit + " to " + newInput);
    setEdit(null);
    setNewInput(null);
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <input
        type="text"
        value={input2}
        onChange={(e) => setInput2(e.target.value)}
      />
      <button onClick={() => createItem(input2)}>Add Item</button>

      {list.map((item) => (
        <div key={item.id}>
          <p>{item.name}</p>
          <button onClick={() => setEdit(item.id)}>
            Rename Item {item.id}
          </button>
          <button onClick={() => deleteItem(item.id)}>Delete Item</button>
        </div>
      ))}

      {edit && (
        <div>
          <input
            type="text"
            value={newInput}
            onChange={(e) => setNewInput(e.target.value)}
          />
          <button onClick={() => renameItem()}>Rename</button>
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

There are other better solutions, such as turning  the `{edit && ...}` part to an component. This should get your code working for now.

I also left out the code to actually rename the item, you should be able to do that yourself also.